# Filter sentence by word length

Tags: python

I have to get a sentence from the user and an integer, divide that sentence into words. And then count the characters in each word. Each word that has more characters than the integer put in from the user is supposed to be printed. So if the user puts in the sentence `"i love cats"` and the number `3`. All the words that have more than 3 characters (in this case just love) are supposed to appear as well as the amount of characters it contains (in this case 4). The problem is that I don't know how to get the program to count the letters in each specific word. Is there a way that I can cut a list into sublists and then count the characters in each sublist?

Comment: Is "cats" no more than three characters...?

Answer (score 4):

If you can isolate the word in a string, you can simply use [`len`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) to get the number of letters.
To isolate those words, you can split the string on whitespace using [`.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).
Other than that, iterate through the words with a for loop, or use a list comprehension.

```
s = "i love cats"
n = 3
[(x, len(x)) for x in s.split() if len(x) > n]
```

Prints

```
[('love', 4), ('cats', 4)]
```