# Need to find strings in a list with more than a certain amount of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find certain words in a list that have more than a certain amount of characters.
I tried this but it just returns the original sentence as a list when it should be returning the strings with more than 5 characters.

```
def my_func(sentence):
    
    answ = sentence.split()
    
    for x in answ:
        
        if len(x) >= 5:
            return x
        
        else:
            return answ
```

Comment: If the first word in your sentence has less than 5 characters you will return the whole list.

Comment: `return [x for x in sentence.split() if len(x) >= 5]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter sentence by word length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618561/filter-sentence-by-word-length)

Comment: Or perhaps this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420726/find-all-words-with-a-given-length-in-python

Comment: @KlausD. thanks that worked but how would i go about rejoining them with the original sentence? For example, 'Hey hello world' would return 'Hey olleh dlrow'

Comment: Please do not ask more than one question per question and try to research on your own first.

Answer (score 1):

your if is returning on the else, remove the else and just return the if statement

Answer (score 1):

The code is just returning the word with size greater than 5 letters and if not found returning the sentence as List, which is not semantically correct.

The code below might solve your problem.

```
def my_func(sentence):
    answ = sentence.split()
    retList = []
    for x in answ:
        if len(x) >= 5:
            retList.append(x)
    return retList
```

Comment: It's doing the right thing, however list comprehension would be very welcome here

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(sentence):
    return [i for i in sentence.split() if len(i) > 5]

s = "Hello, my name is Stephan"
print(f(s))
     
--->["Hello", "Stephan"]
```

This will return a list which contains each word that has more than 5 characters.
The method that i used is called list comprehension.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `filter` function to filter out the  value which is fulfilling the condition ie taking only those words which have more than equal to 5 characters

```
 def func(sentence):
     return list(filter(lambda word: len(word)>=5,sentence.split()))
```

Comment: can you provide a little more explaination?